# 2D Slot machine type animation on GTK+

Tags: c, animation, gtk, graphics2d

I have written a basic slot machine simulation using C and GTK under Linux. The slot machine is 5 reels with each reel having 3 symbols. To "animate" the spinning action I'm just using an animated GIF with an array 3,5 of GtkImages.

I'd like to actually have it look like a proper slot machine where a vertical animation is done for each reel. I would imagine that I'd need to build a pixmap or pixbuf from the symbols on the reel, use g_timer_add() to change the visiable portion of the pixmap on the GtkImage. I'm new to Gtk+ so if anybody has some simple example of this type of animation or good documentation, I would be forever grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you might be better off using a game programming toolkit for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a GtkDrawingArea instead of a GtkImage, so you can draw there as you want. Put all your possible images in a vertical PNG image, as if you had unrolled the reels. Then load this into a pixbuf, create a surface for it using cairo. You'll just have to draw a small subset of that big image using cairo, which you can refer to by a vertical offset to that big image. Use a timer with g_timer_add to make it refresh with a enough frames per second (calculate the speed you need). Don't take the timer callback for granted, there may be delays in the firing of the callback. Best is achieved by using a GTimer, starting it a the time you want to make the reels spin, and in the g_timer_add callback, measure the time elapsed since you started the GTimer. This will allow you to calculate the offset to your image.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and helpful response.

Comment: BTW, to draw in a GtkDrawingArea, give a look to the configure-event to track widget size changes, and "expose-event" (for GTK2), or "draw" event (for GTK3) to handle the drawing.